# Unique value validation in FormControl of FormArray

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am developing Job form where user can enter his hobbies in the Job Form. I have applied required validation on hobbyName formcontrol, but how can I validate hobby name which should be unique if there is more than one hobby.

Below is my ts code

```js
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup,FormArray,FormBuilder,Validators } from "@angular/forms"
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  jobForm:FormGroup
  constructor(private jobfb:FormBuilder){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.jobForm = this.jobfb.group({
      hobbies:this.jobfb.array([
        this.createHobbyFormGroup()
      ])
    })
  }

  addHobby(){
    let hobbies = this.jobForm.controls.hobbies as FormArray;
    hobbies.push(this.createHobbyFormGroup());
  }

  

  createHobbyFormGroup(){
    return this.jobfb.group({
      hobbyName:['',Validators.required]
    });
  }

}
```

below is my Html code

```html
<button (click)="addHobby()">Add Hobby</button>
<table>
  <tr [formGroup]="hobbyFG" *ngFor="let hobbyFG of jobForm.controls.hobbies.controls;">
    <input formControlName="hobbyName"/>
  </tr>
</table>
<button [disabled]="!jobForm.valid">Submit</button>
```

whenever user click on add button, at that time new FormGroup will be added in the FormArray.

I am not able to figure out how can I validate the hobby name, which should be unique?

Please guide.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43577894/angular-uniqueness-validator-in-formarray

Answer (score 2):

Ok,you can use `RxwebValidators` package,I have implemented it its working.Shared below my code.

**In ts file(import in app module)**

```
    import { RxwebValidators } from '@rxweb/reactive-form-validators';

    export class ProductComponent implements OnInit ,Product {
    public complexForm: FormGroup = this.builder.group({
    'firstName' : ['',[Validators.required,Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$')]],
      'lastName': ['', Validators.minLength(5)],
      hobbies:this.builder.array([
        this.createHobbyFormGroup()
      ]),
      'gender' : 'Female',
      'hiking' : false,
      'running' : false,
      'swimming' : false
    });

    addHobby(){
    let hobbies = this.complexForm.controls.hobbies as FormArray;
    hobbies.push(this.createHobbyFormGroup());
  }

  createHobbyFormGroup(){
    return this.builder.group({
      hobbyName:['',RxwebValidators.unique()]
    });
  }



 }
```

**In Html**

```
    <table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">hobby Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr [formGroup]="skillGroup" *ngFor="let skillGroup of complexForm.controls.hobbies.controls;let i = index;">
      <th scope="row">{{i+ 1}}</th>
      <td><input type="text" formControlName="hobbyName" class="form-control"  />
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>hobbies</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" [formControl]="complexForm.controls['hobbies']">
  </div>
```

I hope it will be helpful :)

Comment: this validator doesn't work for looping an array and setting in ```FormArray```

Comment: you can check by clicking on the ```abc``` button in this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/unique-value-validation-in-formarray-reactive-for-nempha?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: this works well but the only problem is the dependency that has to be used. Its size is almost 4mb which could be problmatic. Instead I have tried to solve the problem by using custom validator

Answer (score 0):

I have created a custom validator which will check if there is any duplicate hobby that user has entered and if it finds duplicate then it returns the validation error.

Here is the [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/unique-value-validation?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for the same.

Note: I have created custom validator inside the component itself. But you can have a separate ts file for the same.

If there is anything that I missed please let me know I would be happy to help