# Unique item name validator in Angular FormArray

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I want validate the item name text must be unique. I have refered SO links, but links examples are not working for me. I tried to comment on respective answer, but I don't have a much reputation to do that.

**Link 1:** [Angular - Uniqueness validator in FormArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43577894/angular-uniqueness-validator-in-formarray)

**Link 2 :** [Unique value validation in FormControl of FormArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53921073/unique-value-validation-in-formcontrol-of-formarray)

below is my current code:

```js
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup,FormBuilder,FormArray } from "@angular/forms"
import { RxwebValidators } from "@rxweb/reactive-form-validators"


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  implements OnInit {

public uniqueRowForm: FormGroup; 

constructor(private fb:FormBuilder){

}


ngOnInit() {
  this.uniqueRowForm  = this.fb.group({
    items:this.fb.array([]),
  });
  this.adduserItem();
}

  

  adduserItem(){
    let items = <FormArray>this.uniqueRowForm.controls.items;
    items.push(this.fb.group({
      name:['',RxwebValidators.unique()]
    }));
  }

  

  
}
```

below is my HTML code:

```html
<button (click)="adduserItem()">Add Item </button>
 <table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Item</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr [formGroup]="item" *ngFor="let item of uniqueRowForm.controls.items.controls;let i = index;">
     <td><input type="text" formControlName="name" class="form-control"  />
     <span *ngIf="item.controls.name.errors.unique">not unique</span>
     </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Stackblitz example but not working as per my requirement : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-paqxqs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Please help.

Comment: If you open the developer console (F12) while viewing your stackblitz, you will see the issue. Correct it. Then, check to see that the validators package you are using actually has a validator named *unique*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `?` at the end of your `errors` object to insure that it is not undefined.

```
<span *ngIf="item.controls.name.errors?.unique">not unique</span>
```