# Expression has changed after it was checked in Angular using Reactive Forms

Tags: angular

I'm doing a web application in Angular 6 and I'm using Reactive Forms. I have a Form Group with an array and I am setting the values in `ngOnInit`. I have a custom validator to know if the field called `id` is unique.

```
officesFormGroup: FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.officesFormGroup = this.fb.group({
      offices: this.fb.array([], Validators.required)
    });
  }

ngOnInit() {
      this.setOffices();
  }

setOffices() {
    const control = this.officesForm;

    this.company.offices.forEach((office, index) => {
      control.push(this.fb.group({
        id: office.id,
        name: office.name,
        address: office.address,
        services: this.fb.array([], Validators.required)
      }, {validator: this.officeValidator.bind(this)}));
  }

officeValidator(control: AbstractControl) {
    const id = control.get('id').value;

    if (id !== null && id !== '') {
      const offices: Office[] = this.officesForm.value;

      const isIdUnique = offices.map(office => office.id)
        .some(value => value === id);

      if (isIdUnique) {
        control.get('id').setErrors({unavailable: true});
      } else {
        control.get('id').setErrors(null);
      }
    }
  }

get officesForm() {
    return this.officesFormGroup.get('offices') as FormArray;
  }
```

To add a new office to the array:

```
addOffice() {
    const office = this.fb.group({
      id: [null, Validators.required],
      name: [null, Validators.required],
      address: [null, Validators.required],
      services: this.fb.array([], Validators.required)
    }, {validator: this.officeValidator.bind(this)});

    this.officesForm.push(office);
  }
```

> ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed
>   after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: false'. Current value:
>   'ngIf: true'.

When the page is loaded for the first time, the field called `id` appears red, like it has errors, which is wrong. It should check for unique if the user adds another office and writed something in the `id` field.

My goal is, if the user adds a new office or try to edit the `id` of an existing office, check if the `id` is unique, I mean, if no other office has the same `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used in my application unique validator of `@rxweb/reactive-form-validators` to check whether Id is unique by using `RxwebValidators.unique()` in my formControl instance, because at a certain level i was facing the same issue.

I have applied the unique validator on Id property. See the below code

Component.ts :

```
export class UniqueValidatorComponent implements OnInit {


officesFormGroup: FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.officesFormGroup = this.fb.group({
      offices: this.fb.array([])
    });
  }

ngOnInit() {

  this.addOffice();

  }
addOffice() {
    const office = this.fb.group({
      id: [null,[ Validators.required,RxwebValidators.unique()]],
      name: [null, Validators.required],
      address: [null, Validators.required],
      services: this.fb.array([], Validators.required,)
    });
     this.officesForm.push(office);
  }
get officesForm() {
    return this.officesFormGroup.get('offices') as FormArray;
  }


}
```

Please refer this example : [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-drrnyp?file=src%2Fapp%2Funique-complete.component.ts)

Refer this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53995239/unique-item-name-validator-in-angular-formarray) related to unique validation

Comment: `RxwebValidators` will check if the `id` you added already exist on another office int he array, right? How? I don't understand where or how `RxwebValidators` is comparing all the `id`'s.

Comment: @RRGT19 Once you put on unique validator on respective column, the unique validator will validate value with other rows of the column. you can refer this article : https://medium.com/@oojhaajay/quick-solution-unique-value-validation-in-formarray-of-angular-7f2f36493aaa